# Ruby on Rails Syntax <% vs <%=

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, erb

I am new to ruby and rails altogether. The tutorial I am following doesn't explain the difference between <% and <%= tag. For exmaple:

```
<% @statuses.each do |status| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= status.name %></td>
    <td><%= status.content %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Show', status %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_status_path(status) %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', status, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
  </tr>
 <% end %>
```

The loop opens up with just <% and within it the tags open up with <%= .

So what's the difference?

Thanks

Comment: [This](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_view_overview.html#erb)

Comment: This is not specific to Rails, but also the case for other templating languages such as jsp, asp which also use <%= %> and <% %> format.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`<% %>` and `<%= %>` both execute Ruby code.

`<% %>` will execute Ruby code, but will not render the return value into html.
`<%= %>` will execute Ruby code, and will render the return value into html.